# Exercice of types in Ocaml

Tags: types, ocaml

I have to compute fonctions with the following type :

```
f8 : 'a -> 'a -> 'b -> 'b -> 'a * 'b

f5 : ('a -> 'b * 'c) -> ('b -> 'c -> 'd) -> ('d * bool -> 'e) -> 'a -> 'a -> 'e
```

Here what I wrote :

```
let f8 a b c d = (a,c);;

let f5 f g h x y = h (g f a, true);;
```

I get :

```
val f8 : 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'a * 'c = <fun>

val f5 : 'a -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> ('c * bool -> 'd) -> 'b -> 'e -> 'd =
  <fun>
```

For f8, I dont know how to show that there is 2 difference types and for f5, I din't know how to separate the b*c with have to form a g(b c).

Thank you in advance,

Alice

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks answers to what clearly is an homework

Comment: How can you force 2 variables to have the same type ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two values with the same unknown type, you essentially have two indistinguishable objects `x` and `y`. There is one interesting operation that you can do on such pair of objects: swap them.

And if you want to be sure that it is not possible to track their origin, you can swap them conditionally:

```ml
let random = false (* chosen with a fair coin *)
let mix x y = if random then x, y else y, x
```

The type of `mix` is then `'a -> 'a -> 'a * 'a` and it should be enough to build both `f5` and `f8`.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare two values they infer to the same type:

```
# let same x y = x == y;;
val same : 'a -> 'a -> bool = <fun>
# let g a b c = let _ = same a b in c;;
val g : 'a -> 'a -> 'b -> 'b = <fun>
```

And for f5 you have to extract the values from the pair:

```
let (b, c) = f1 a in
```

now you have values of type 'b and 'c and can create a value of type 'd and then 'e.

Of cause you can also just annotate your functions:

```
# let same (x : 'a) (y : 'a) = ();;
val f : 'a -> 'a -> unit = <fun>
```

But that is probably not the goal of the exercise.

Comment: Note that the  `same` function will raise an exception for non-comparable types.

Comment: Changed it to `==` to avoid problems with recursive / cyclic types.